# Get numerical part of file name in bash

Tags: bash

My file names are something like

```
AAA_BBB_CCC_6-28_04-12-33PM/fetch_352.txt
AAA_BBB_CCC_6-28_04-12-33PM/fetch_351.txt
AAA_BBB_CCC_6-28_04-12-33PM/fetch_2.txt
```

How can I get numerical value `352`, `351`, `2` from it in bash?

I tried

```
ls | sed -e s/[^0-9]//g
```

but it gives me something like 628041233352

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk -F'[_.]' '{print $(NF-1)}' <<< "AAA_BBB_CCC_6-28_04-12-33PM/fetch_352.txt
> AAA_BBB_CCC_6-28_04-12-33PM/fetch_351.txt                                                                           
> AAA_BBB_CCC_6-28_04-12-33PM/fetch_2.txt"   

352
351
2
```

Use delimiters `_` and `.` and print the penultimate field.

Answer (score 0):

Use shell [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) operators.

```
filename=AAA_BBB_CCC_6-28_04-12-33PM/fetch_352.txt
num=${filename##*_} # remove everything through the last _
num=${num%.txt} # remove .txt suffix
echo $num # should print 352
```